# How to get href value of active tab inside li list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, html-lists

How to get href value of profileTab_51069

```html
<ul id="TabView" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li id="myhomeTab" class=""><a href="#home" class="" data-toggle="tab">&nbsp;&nbsp;My Home&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
  <li id="2" class=""><a href="#profileTab_51073" data-toggle="tab">PSC:51073 </a></li>
  <li id="3" class="active"><a href="#profileTab_51069" data-toggle="tab">PSC:51069</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: also id starting with numeric is not good use letters. you can have `$("#li3").find("a").attr("href")`

Comment: This is what worked for me.  `$('ul#TabView li.active a').attr('href');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use id of ul element along with class selector active to find descendant child li element having class active:

```
$('#TabView li.active').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `$("#TabView li.active a").html()` It takes the `li` that has the class `active` and get the value of the `link`

```js
console.log($("#TabView li.active a").html())


// Example code
$("#TabView li").click(function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $("#TabView li.active").removeClass("active")
    $(this).addClass("active")
    console.log($(this).find("a").html())
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="TabView" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li id="myhomeTab" class=""><a href="#home" class="" data-toggle="tab">&nbsp;&nbsp;My Home&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
  <li id="2" class=""><a href="#profileTab_51073" data-toggle="tab">PSC:51073 </a></li>
  <li id="3" class="active"><a href="#profileTab_51069" data-toggle="tab">PSC:51069</a></li>
</ul>
```